# How to get the YouTube channel name from the url

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I want to use the importxml in the spreadsheet to get the YouTube channel name from the url, but I get the following error.
How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A4)), 
 "where Col1 contains '\x22channelName\x22:\x22'", 0), ":\\x22(.+)\\x22$")
```

[image]